# Google play store console, how to edit what is new section?

Tags: android

In the new Google play store console, how to edit what is new section, after app has been  rolled out ?

Answer (score 6):

**From Beta to production :**

Go to `App Releases`, if you are pushing from Beta then push the release to production 
then under `release to production`,

Fill out the section under `What's new in this release?` for What you have improved or included in this release, there is an option of even copying from prev release.

**Direct to production :**

While for pushing a release direct to production, In `App Releases` page
Press `MANAGE PRODUCTION` button and then

`CREATE RELEASE` Button and then fill out the `What's new in this release?` section.

**Apk already in production :**

In `App Releases` page, press `MANAGE PRODUCTION` button and then click on `View all APK details` which looks something like this : [image: View all APK details button image]

For reference this button is placed on right on the Manage Production/Release page as shown below :
[image: Release page screenshot]

After `APK details` is open you can edit/change `What's new in this version?` section.

Comment: The APK was already pushed to production and it is now available at playstore. But now, we want to change / edit 'What's new' content. How to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you ! When I click on [i] icon 'View all apk details', it shows me a window with 'What's new' field as blank (without my old content).  Will it completely overwrite the existing content of 'Whats new' ? Or, will it append whatever I add ?

Comment: If it's blank that means there is no content for 'whats new' for that release. In that case you can copy paste the content from any other release if you had filled it in the past or could just write a new one.. Hope this helps :)